# Can I check a small array of bools in one go?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, boolean

There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044590/can-i-check-in-c-if-an-array-is-all-0-or-false), but the user in that question seemed to have a much larger array, or vector. If I have:

```
bool boolArray[4];
```

And I want to check if all elements are false, I can check [ 0 ], [ 1 ] , [ 2 ] and [ 3 ] either separately, or I can loop through it. Since (as far as I know) false should have value 0 and anything other than 0 is true, I thought about simply doing:

```
if ( *(int*) boolArray) { }
```

This works, but I realize that it relies on bool being one byte and int being four bytes. If I cast to (std::uint32_t) would it be OK, or is it still a bad idea? I just happen to have 3 or 4 bools in an array and was wondering if this is safe, and if not if there is a better way to do it.

Also, in the case I end up with more than 4 bools but less than 8 can I do the same thing with a std::uint64_t or unsigned long long or something?

Comment: What about using a `std::bitset`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I haven't thought about that, I just used what was obvious to me at the time, an array. BTW, this site is getting weird. This may be a really dumb question so I welcome all downvotes, but I got a downvote literally within 5 seconds of posting it.

Comment: _"This may be a really dumb question so I welcome all downvotes, but I got a downvote literally within 5 seconds of posting it."_  Sorry, it was my DV. Reading about array or vector of bools rings my alarm bells. I retracted my DV now.

Comment: Well I'll look into std::bitset I guess. I just used an array as it was most obvious to me, I just used it for left, middle and right mouse buttons down.

Comment: *I just used it for left, middle and right mouse buttons down.* => Have you thought about using an `enum class MouseButtonDown: std::uint8_t { Left = 1, Middle = 2, Right = 4 }` and manipulate the enum as a bitset?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to find code that is more complex, fragile, and hard to understand than a simple OR of the various tests?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not trying to find anything more complex. I wrote this a while ago and it turned out that I had allocated an array of 4 bools for mouse buttons. This was the first thought I had instead of checking each one. I haven't used std::bitset before.

Comment: @Zebrafish Well, you ask if there is any better way to do it. In what way could anything be better than the simple, straightforward OR of the various tests? What are you expecting could be improved exactly?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I asked if it was OK to cast the four bools to int or uint32_t and check for a zero value. Besides checking [0], [1], [2] and [3] separately this was my first idea. I never mentioned anything about bitwise OR'ing. My approach seems to be a bad idea because it violates the strict aliasing rule, so I accepted the answer that suggests to use std::bitset::any(). (I hadn't used std::bitset before).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Vector of bools is perfectly fine as it uses bitset internally anyways.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As πάντα ῥεῖ noticed in comments, [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is probably the best way to deal with that in UB-free manner.

```
std::bitset<4> boolArray {};
if(boolArray.any()) {
    //do the thing
}
```

If you want to stick to arrays, you could use [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), but this requires (possibly peculiar to the readers) usage of functor which just returns its argument:

```
bool boolArray[4];
if(std::any_of(std::begin(boolArray), std::end(boolArray), [](bool b){return b;}) {
    //do the thing
}
```

Type-punning 4 `bool`s to `int` might be a bad idea - you cannot be sure of the size of each of the types. It probably will work on most architectures, but `std::bitset` is guaranteed to work everywhere, under any circumstances.

Comment: "Order positions are counted from the rightmost bit", so that if I do std::bitset<4> foo; foo[1] = true; the output from cout is 0010. I know it doesn't matter, but do you know why the first index is the last bit?

Comment: @Zebrafish Probably to make it more resembling clasical bit operations. `myBitset[3]` is equivalent to `myInt & (1 << 3)`. This way you can transfer simply from the old C way of masking bits to C++ `std::bitset` more easily. I guess storing array of bools wasn't its primary purpose ;)

Comment: I worked with a compiler that would do this automatically.  So you may want to check out how your compiler might optimize bit checks.

Comment: Can confirm with godbolt that the first one optimises nicely but the second one doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/t97Dr9

Answer (score 10):

Several answers have already explained good alternatives, particularly `std::bitset` and `std::any_of()`. I am writing separately to point out that, unless you know something we don't, it is *not safe* to type pun between `bool` and `int` in this fashion, for several reasons:

1. `int` might not be four bytes, as multiple answers have pointed out.
2. M.M points out in the comments that `bool` might not be one byte. I'm not aware of any real-world architectures in which this has ever been the case, but it is nevertheless spec-legal. It (probably) can't be smaller than a byte unless the compiler is doing some very elaborate hide-the-ball chicanery with its memory model, and a multi-byte bool seems rather useless. Note however that a byte need not be 8 bits in the first place.
3. `int` can have [trap representations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6725981/1340389). That is, it is legal for certain bit patterns to cause undefined behavior when they are cast to `int`. This is rare on modern architectures, but might arise on (for example) [ia64](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040119-00/?p=41003), or any system with signed zeros.
4. Regardless of whether you have to worry about any of the above, **your code violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/1340389),** so compilers are free to "optimize" it under the assumption that the bools and the int are entirely separate objects with non-overlapping lifetimes. For example, the compiler might decide that the code which initializes the bool array is a [dead store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_store) and eliminate it, because the bools "must have" ceased to exist* at some point before you dereferenced the pointer. More complicated situations can also arise relating to register reuse and load/store reordering. All of these infelicities are expressly permitted by the C++ standard, which says the behavior is undefined when you engage in this kind of type punning.

You should use one of the alternative solutions provided by the other answers.

---

* It is legal (with some qualifications, particularly regarding alignment) to reuse the memory pointed to by `boolArray` by casting it to int and storing an integer, although if you actually want to do this, you must then pass `boolArray` through [`std::launder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382728/1340389) if you want to read the resulting int later. Regardless, the compiler is entitled to assume that you have done this once it sees the read, even if you don't call launder.

Comment: Bool might by multi-byte if accessing a single byte is noticeably slower (if it's a matter of loading a 32-bit quantity into a register, and then accessing the appropriate byte for example).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::bitset<N>::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/all_any_none):

Any returns `true` if any of the bits are set to `true`, otherwise `false`.

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <bitset>        

int main ()
{
  std::bitset<4> foo;
  // modify foo here


  if (foo.any())
    std::cout << foo << " has " << foo.count() << " bits set.\n";
  else
    std::cout << foo << " has no bits set.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

[Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UlbmDkhRqDhs37X2)

If you want to return `true` if all or none of the bits set to on, you can use `std::bitset<N>::all` or `std::bitset<N>::none` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library has what you need in the form of the [std::all_of, std::any_of, std::none_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

...And for the obligatory "roll your own" answer, we can provide a simple "or"-like function for any array `bool[N]`, like so:

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr bool or_all(const bool (&bs)[N]) {
    for (bool b : bs) {
        if (b) { return b; }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Or more concisely,

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr bool or_all(const bool (&bs)[N]) {
    for (bool b : bs) { if (b) { return b; } }
    return false;
}
```

This also has the benefit of both short-circuiting like `||`, and being optimised out entirely if calculable at compile time.

---

Apart from that, if you want to examine the original idea of type-punning `bool[N]` to some other type to simplify observation, I would *very much* recommend that you <strike>don't do that</strike> view it as `char[N2]` instead, where `N2 == (sizeof(bool) * N)`.  This would allow you to provide a simple representation viewer that can automatically scale to the viewed object's actual size, allow iteration over its individual bytes, and allow you to more easily determine whether the representation matches specific values (such as, e.g., zero or non-zero).  I'm not entirely sure off the top of my head whether such examination would invoke any UB, but I can say for certain that any such type's construction cannot be a viable constant-expression, due to requiring a reinterpret cast to `char*` or `unsigned char*` or similar (either explicitly, or in `std::memcpy()`), and thus couldn't as easily be optimised out.

Comment: Wow, I just learned you can use range-based for loops with simple arrays. I thought it based on begin() and end(). Thanks.

Comment: @Zebrafish It is, but `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are defined for arrays.